# DataGridView add column by code

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.0

I need to add columns to my `DataGridView` dynamically... to do this here is my code:

```
dgv.Columns.Clear();
dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
{
    var newColumn = new DataGridViewColumn(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());
    newColumn.Name = fields[i];
    newColumn.DataPropertyName = fields[i];
    newColumn.HeaderText = fields[i];
    dgv.Columns.Add(newColumn);
}
```

And after, when I link my query to the `DataSource` I retrieve this error:

> The value can't be null.
>       Parameter name: columnName

And the strange thing is that here is my `DataGridView`/`DataTable` situation:

[image: error]

The names seems right...

The other strange thing is that the first row is shown, but the others gives the exception *(the query is OK and the data are valid...)*

here is the code to create the `DataSource` for the table:

```
public DataTable getData()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(item.Query, db.getConnection());
    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter();
    dap.SelectCommand = cmd;
    dap.Fill(ds);

    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

and after:

```
dgv.DataSource = getData();
```

Comment: Might be unrelated, but have you tried `var nextColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();` instead of what is shown in the above example?

Comment: @ghiboz, i can not reproduce an issue with the given code

Comment: @IvanStoev the result is the same :(

Comment: Then it might be useful if you explain what do you mean by "my query", i.e. what is the type of the data source - for instance, `List<T>`, 'T[]`, `BindingList<T>` etc, if yes, the type of T, also are you using intermediate component like `BindingSource` etc.

Comment: Where you are executing that code? And what types is `fields` array

Comment: @IvanStoev I've added the code to create the DataSource and the columns at the moment are only one of string type.

Comment: All I get from the update is that you are using a `DataTable` as a data source. Unfortunately that info is insufficient - as you understand, similar code has been used a billion times and is working. A minimal reproducible example is needed.